# Why did Jules mention music band name here?

Tags: plot-explanation, pulp-fiction

In *Pulp Fiction* (1994), Jimmie does this favour for Jules and Vinnie. He hides a body for
them in his garage. Thing is, the body is still in the car where Jules
and Vinnie did him in. Jimmie's worried what'll happen when his wife gets
home and finds out what he's gotten them into. He tells Vincent and Jules
they need to help him figure out this situation before his wife gets home:

> Jimmie: You gotta make some phone calls? You gotta call some people?
> Well, then, do it, and then get the fuck out of my house before  she
> gets here.
>
> Jules: That's **Kool and the Gang**. We don't wanna fuck your shit up.
> All I wanna do is call my people and get 'em to bring us in.

Why did Jules mention music band name here?

Comment: Sounds to me like an even cooler way to say "that's cool".

Comment: He earlier calls another guy "Flock of Seagulls", so it might be verbal habit of free-association that he does regularly.

Comment: Well, the kid did have a haircut similar to what I remember the lead singer of FoS had...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jules is just being deliberately lighthearted in order to try to calm Jimmie down.

He's being blamed for bringing the whole messy situation to Jimmie's house. Saying "Kool and the Gang" is just an alternative jokey way of saying "Cool", meaning Ok or Yes.